# Docker compose environment variables specified with env_file parameter not working inside the dockerfile

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, fig

This is a snippet of my `docker-compose.yml` file which I'm running with `docker-compose build percona_dev`.

```
percona_dev:
  build: docker/percona
  dockerfile: percona-dev
  env_file: docker.env
```

I've specified environment variables in `docker.env` like this:

```
USERNAME=xxx
PASSWORD=xxx
DESKTOP_IP=192.168.1.1
PLAYBOOK_LOCATION=/path/to/location/
```

This is the relevant portion of my `Dockerfile` called `percona-dev`:

```
FROM percona:5.6.24
MAINTAINER xxx

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wget

RUN wget --ftp-user=$USERNAME --ftp-password=$PASSWORD ftp://$DESKTOP_IP/$PLAYBOOK_LOCATION/inventory/localhost -O /tmp/playbook/hosts

EXPOSE 3306
ENTRYPOINT [“/usr/bin/mysql”]
```

Unfortunately the environment variables don't get recognized and the build fails with:

```
Step 5 : RUN wget --ftp-user=$USERNAME --ftp-password=$PASSWORD ftp://$DESKTOP_IP/$PLAYBOOK_LOCATION/inventory/localhost -O /tmp/playbook/hosts
 ---> Running in 3595b5ce9581
ftp:////inventory/localhost: Invalid host name.
Service 'percona_dev' failed to build:
```

How do I make sure I can run the build without exposing sensitive environment variables in my Dockerfile or in thefilesystem layer history of my image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

environment variables are not available to the build step.  See [this proposal](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2163) for making that more obvious in compose and [this feature request](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2111) to support the new build args added to docker 1.9.

The build args will do what you need.